Unable to acquire a buffer item, very likely client tried to acquire more than maxImages buffers
I'm using socket for wireless screencast of client screenbuffers on server. I'm using MediaProjection for screencast. Using below code snippet I'm receiving client screen's screenbuffer on server but not able to receive any buffer after using 2 buffers of
I'm using media projection api and over tcp/ip I'm making application which can do screencast, but not able to acquire more than 2 images if ImageReader instance.
public class MediaProjectionService extends Service {

    private static final String TAG = MediaProjectionService.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final String CHANNEL_ID = "MediaProjectionChannel";
    private static MediaProjection mediaProjection;
    private ImageReader imageReader;
    private ImageWriter imageWriter;
    private String serverIp;
    private int width, height;
    private static Handler handler;
    private List<Image> imageList = new ArrayList<>();
    private static final int IMAGE_BATCH_SIZE = 10;
    private boolean isFirstImage = true;

    public static Intent startIntent(Context context, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MediaProjectionService.class);
        intent.putExtra("RESULT_CODE", resultCode);
        intent.putExtra("DATA", data);
        return intent;
    }

    public static Intent stopIntent(Context context) {
        if (handler != null) {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (mediaProjection != null) {
                        mediaProjection.stop();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MediaProjectionService.class);
        intent.setAction("STOP_PROJECTION");
        return intent;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        createNotificationChannel();

        new Thread(() -> {
            Looper.prepare();
            handler = new Handler();
            Looper.loop();
        }).start();
    }

    private static boolean isStartCommand(Intent intent) {
        return intent.hasExtra("RESULT_CODE") && intent.hasExtra("DATA");
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if (isStartCommand(intent)) {
            serverIp = intent.getStringExtra("server_ip");
            Log.i(TAG, "serverIp: " + serverIp);
            int resultCode = intent.getIntExtra("RESULT_CODE", Activity.RESULT_CANCELED);
            Intent data = intent.getParcelableExtra("DATA");

            startForegroundService();
            startProjection(resultCode, data);
        }

        if ("STOP_PROJECTION".equals(intent.getAction())) {
            stopProjection();
            return START_NOT_STICKY;
        }
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    private void startForegroundService() {
        Notification notification = createNotification();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            startForeground(1, notification, ServiceInfo.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_MEDIA_PROJECTION);
        } else {
            startForeground(1, notification);
        }
    }

    private Notification createNotification() {
        return new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentTitle("Screen Projection")
                .setContentText("Screen projection is running")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .build();
    }

    private void createNotificationChannel() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(
                    CHANNEL_ID,
                    "Screen Projection Service",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
            );
            NotificationManager manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            if (manager != null) {
                manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
            }
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("WrongConstant")
    private void startProjection(int resultCode, Intent data) {
        MediaProjectionManager projectionManager = (MediaProjectionManager) getSystemService(Context.MEDIA_PROJECTION_SERVICE);
        mediaProjection = projectionManager.getMediaProjection(resultCode, data);

        width = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
        height = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;

        imageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(width, height, PixelFormat.RGBA_8888, 2);
        mediaProjection.createVirtualDisplay(
                "ScreenCapture",
                width,
                height,
                getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi,
                0,
                imageReader.getSurface(),
                null,
                new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()));

        imageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(new ClientScreenImageAvailableListener(), new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()));
}

    private void stopProjection() {
        if (mediaProjection != null) {
            mediaProjection.stop();
            mediaProjection = null;
        }
        stopForeground(true); // Remove notification
        stopSelf(); // Stop service
    }

    @SuppressLint("WrongConstant")
    private void startProjection(int resultCode, Intent data) {
        MediaProjectionManager projectionManager = (MediaProjectionManager) getSystemService(Context.MEDIA_PROJECTION_SERVICE);
        mediaProjection = projectionManager.getMediaProjection(resultCode, data);

        width = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
        height = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;

        imageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(width, height, PixelFormat.RGBA_8888, 2);
        mediaProjection.createVirtualDisplay(
                "ScreenCapture",
                width,
                height,
                getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi,
                0,
                imageReader.getSurface(),
                null,
                new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()));

        imageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(new ClientScreenImageAvailableListener(), new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()));
    }

    private class ClientScreenImageAvailableListener implements ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener {
        @Override
        public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Image available from ImageReader.");
            Image image = null;
            try {
                image = reader.acquireLatestImage();
                Image finalImage = image;
                sendImageToServer(finalImage);
                finalImage.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error processing image", e);
            }
        }

        private void sendImageToServer(Image image) {
            try (Socket socket = new Socket(serverIp, 5000);
                 ObjectOutputStream outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream())) {

                Image.Plane[] planes = image.getPlanes();
                ByteBuffer buffer = planes[0].getBuffer();
                int pixelStride = planes[0].getPixelStride();
                int rowStride = planes[0].getRowStride();
                int rowPadding = rowStride - pixelStride * width;

                Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width + rowPadding / pixelStride, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                bitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(buffer);

                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
                byte[] bitmapBytes = baos.toByteArray();

                outputStream.writeObject(bitmapBytes);
                outputStream.flush();

                Log.i(TAG, "Image sent to server successfully.");

                bitmap.recycle();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Failed to send image to server", e);
            }
//            finally {
//                image.close();
//            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}

Here's logs:
2024-08-29 14:00:20.114 27196-27196 MediaProjectionService              com.r.screenmediaprojection   I  serverIp: 0.0.0.0 (my ip is printed here)
2024-08-29 14:00:20.121 27196-27196 CompatibilityChangeReporter         com.r.screenmediaprojection   D  Compat change id reported: 236825255; UID 10748; state: DISABLED
2024-08-29 14:00:20.121 27196-27196 BufferQueueConsumer                 com.r.screenmediaprojection   D  [](id:6a3c00000003,api:0,p:-1,c:27196) connect: controlledByApp=true
2024-08-29 14:00:20.121 27196-27196 CompatibilityChangeReporter         com.r.screenmediaprojection   D  Compat change id reported: 269849258; UID 10748; state: DISABLED
2024-08-29 14:00:20.163 27196-27196 ImeFocusController                  com.r.screenmediaprojection   V  onWindowFocus: DecorView@8ca0efc[MainActivity] softInputMode=STATE_UNSPECIFIED|ADJUST_PAN
2024-08-29 14:00:20.178 27196-27196 MediaProjectionService              com.r.screenmediaprojection   I  Image available from ImageReader.
2024-08-29 14:00:20.182 27196-28395 TrafficStats                        com.r.screenmediaprojection   D  tagSocket(142) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
2024-08-29 14:00:20.187 27196-27196 MediaProjectionService              com.r.screenmediaprojection   I  Image available from ImageReader.
2024-08-29 14:00:20.190 27196-27196 ImageReader_JNI                     com.r.screenmediaprojection   W  Unable to acquire a buffer item, very likely client tried to acquire more than maxImages buffers
2024-08-29 14:00:20.191 27196-28396 TrafficStats                        com.r.screenmediaprojection   D  tagSocket(148) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
2024-08-29 14:00:20.202 27196-27196 MediaProjectionService              com.r.screenmediaprojection   I  Image available from ImageReader.
2024-08-29 14:00:20.202 27196-27196 ImageReader_JNI                     com.r.screenmediaprojection   W  Unable to acquire a buffer item, very likely client tried to acquire more than maxImages buffers
2024-08-29 14:00:20.203 27196-27196 MediaProjectionService              com.r.screenmediaprojection   E  Error processing image
                                                                                                                java.lang.IllegalStateException: maxImages (2) has already been acquired, call #close before acquiring more.
                                                                                                                    at android.media.ImageReader.acquireNextImage(ImageReader.java:672)
                                                                                                                    at android.media.ImageReader.acquireLatestImage(ImageReader.java:552)
                                                                                                                    at com.r.screenmediaprojection.service.MediaProjectionService$ClientScreenImageAvailableListener.onImageAvailable(MediaProjectionService.java:153)
                                                                                                                    at android.media.ImageReader$1.run(ImageReader.java:958)
                                                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:1013)
                                                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:101)
                                                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
                                                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:328)
                                                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:9188)
                                                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:594)
                                                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
2024-08-29 14:00:20.742 27196-28396 VCode/native                        com.r.screenmediaprojection   D  track_event send
2024-08-29 14:00:20.743 27196-28396 OpenGLRenderer                      com.r.screenmediaprojection   D  Bitmap::compress format:Png w:1088 h:2204 quality:100 app_apk:com.r.screenmediaprojection 
2024-08-29 14:00:20.744 27196-28396 libc                                com.r.screenmediaprojection   W  Access denied finding property "vendor.vivo.imageencoder.dump"
2024-08-29 14:00:20.746 27196-28395 VCode/native                        com.r.screenmediaprojection   D  track_event send
2024-08-29 14:00:20.746 27196-28395 OpenGLRenderer                      com.r.screenmediaprojection   D  Bitmap::compress format:Png w:1088 h:2204 quality:100 app_apk:com.r.screenmediaprojection 
2024-08-29 14:00:20.747 27196-28395 libc                                com.r.screenmediaprojection   W  Access denied finding property "vendor.vivo.imageencoder.dump"
2024-08-29 14:00:20.966 27196-28395 MediaProjectionService              com.r.screenmediaprojection   I  Image sent to server successfully.
2024-08-29 14:00:20.967 27196-28395 MediaProjectionService              com.r.screenmediaprojection   D  Image closed after processing
2024-08-29 14:00:20.973 27196-28396 MediaProjectionService              com.r.screenmediaprojection   I  Image sent to server successfully.
2024-08-29 14:00:20.974 27196-28396 MediaProjectionService              com.r.screenmediaprojection   D  Image closed after processing

How do I send more than two images using imagereader? for 3rd image which I'm trying to acquire it's throwing mentioned error. Please share suggestions to fix it!

Did you start the mediaProjection after starting ForegroundService and giving mediaProjection permission? Are you getting this error after starting mediaProjection? If yes then let me know.

Yes, after starting media projection I'm getting this error. I've shared additional code snippets, please checkout

check my provided code and let me know it's working or not.

it's still throwing same error... here's logs for same. Please share your insights! FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.r.screenmediaprojection, PID: 10947 java.lang.IllegalStateException: maxImages (2) has already been acquired, call #close before acquiring more. at android.media.ImageReader.acquireNextImage(ImageReader.java:672) at com.r.screenmediaprojection.service.MediaProjectionService$2.onImageAvailable(MediaProjectionService.java:195)

I think image is not closing properly, after processing the acquired image. Try to put some log then check it and also provide full error in my responded answer's comment.

Try this,
private void captureScreen() {
    DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    int screenWidth = metrics.widthPixels;
    int screenHeight = metrics.heightPixels;
    int screenDensity = metrics.densityDpi;

    imageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(screenWidth, screenHeight, PixelFormat.RGBA_8888, 2);

    mediaProjection.createVirtualDisplay(
            "ScreenCapture"
            , imageReader.getWidth()
            , imageReader.getHeight()
            , DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM
            , DisplayManager.VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAG_AUTO_MIRROR
            , imageReader.getSurface()
            , null, null);

    imageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {
        @Override
        public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
            Image image = null;
            try {
                image = reader.acquireNextImage();
                if (image != null) {
                    Bitmap bitmap = imageToBitmap(image);
                    // send this bitmap to the server
                    //androidWebServer.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                }
            } finally {
                if (image != null) {
                    image.close();
                }
            }
        }
    }, new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()));
}

private Bitmap imageToBitmap(Image image) {
    Image.Plane[] planes = image.getPlanes();
    ByteBuffer buffer = planes[0].getBuffer();
    int pixelStride = planes[0].getPixelStride();
    int rowStride = planes[0].getRowStride();
    int rowPadding = rowStride - pixelStride * image.getWidth();

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(image.getWidth() + rowPadding / pixelStride, image.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    buffer.rewind();
    bitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(buffer);
    return bitmap;
}


AndroidRuntime E FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: , PID: 23796 java.lang.IllegalStateException: maxImages (2) has already been acquired, call #close before acquiring more. at android.media.ImageReader.acquireNextImage(ImageReader.java:672) at .service.MediaProjectionService$2.onImageAvailable(MediaProjectionService.java:195)at android.media.ImageReader$1.run(ImageReader.java:958)at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:1013)at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:101)at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)

continued.. at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:328)at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:9188)at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:594)at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099) OpenGLRenderer D Bitmap::compress format:Png w:1088 h:2204 quality:100 app_apk:libc W Access denied finding property "vendor.vivo.imageencoder.dump"

After integrating suggested code got same error

Finally found solution for this issue, Here's working code to fix this issue:
Use below flags to pass in Displaymanager:
private int getVirtualDisplayFlags() {
        return DisplayManager.VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAG_OWN_CONTENT_ONLY | DisplayManager.VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAG_PUBLIC;
    }

Start Media Projection code as below:
private void startProjection(int resultCode, Intent data) {
        MediaProjectionManager mpManager =
                (MediaProjectionManager) getSystemService(Context.MEDIA_PROJECTION_SERVICE);
        if (mediaProjection == null) {
            mMediaProjection = mpManager.getMediaProjection(resultCode, data);
            mDensity = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi;
            WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
            mDisplay = windowManager.getDefaultDisplay();

            // create virtual display depending on device width / height
            createVirtualDisplay();
        }
    }
@SuppressLint("WrongConstant")
    private void createVirtualDisplay() {
        // get width and height
        mWidth = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
        mHeight = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
        Log.i(TAG, "Width: " + mWidth + ", Height: " + mHeight);

        // start capture reader
        mImageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(mWidth, mHeight, PixelFormat.RGBA_8888, 2);
        mVirtualDisplay = mMediaProjection.createVirtualDisplay("screencap", mWidth, mHeight,
                mDensity, getVirtualDisplayFlags(), mImageReader.getSurface(), null, handler);
        mImageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(new ImageAvailableListener2(), handler);
    }

private class ImageAvailableListener2 implements ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener {
        @Override
        public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
            try {
                socket = new Socket("your ip", 5555);
                objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }

            FileOutputStream fos = null;
            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            try (Image image = reader.acquireLatestImage()) {
                if (image != null) {
                    Image.Plane[] planes = image.getPlanes();
                    ByteBuffer buffer = planes[0].getBuffer();
                    int pixelStride = planes[0].getPixelStride();
                    int rowStride = planes[0].getRowStride();
                    int rowPadding = rowStride - pixelStride * mWidth;

                    bitmap = imageToBitmap(image);
                    Log.i(TAG, "bitmap: "+bitmap);

                    sendImageToServer(image);
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (fos != null) {
                    try {
                        fos.close();
                    } catch (IOException ioe) {
                        ioe.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                if (bitmap != null) {
                    bitmap.recycle();
                }

            }
        }
        private void sendImageToServer(Image image) {
            try (Socket socket = new Socket(serverIp, 5000);
                 ObjectOutputStream outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream())) {

                Image.Plane[] planes = image.getPlanes();
                ByteBuffer buffer = planes[0].getBuffer();
                int pixelStride = planes[0].getPixelStride();
                int rowStride = planes[0].getRowStride();
                int rowPadding = rowStride - pixelStride * mWidth;
                // Check if width and height are greater than 0
                if (mWidth > 0 && mHeight > 0) {
                    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mWidth + rowPadding / pixelStride, mHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                    bitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(buffer);

                    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
                    byte[] bitmapBytes = baos.toByteArray();

                    saveBitmapToFile(bitmap);
                    outputStream.writeObject(bitmapBytes);
                    outputStream.flush();

                    Log.i(TAG, "Image sent to server successfully.");

                    bitmap.recycle();
                } else {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Invalid width or height: width=" + width + ", height=" + height);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Failed to send image to server", e);
            }
        }

    }



What change did you make in this code? Is it only flag or anything else?

Yes, I only changed flags..
